# iOS 7 Safari forces bold buttons

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, stylesheet

I have a button with the following HTML and CSS:

```
<button type="button" class="wrapper">
    <p class="text">Preferences</p>
</button>


.wrapper {
    height: 80px;
    top: 0px;
    line-height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 34px;
}

.text {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto 0 auto 0;
    padding: 0 21px 0 20px;
    font-size: 26px!important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 32px!important;
    font-weight: 500!important;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

In every browser it renders correctly except in iOS 7 Safari where the font is **BOLD**.  I am assuming Apple is overriding my CSS and forcing the font to bold.  Is there a way to make the font-weight "normal"

Comment: probably due to the user-agent on that device. Have you found the user agent property that is making the text bold? It may be a different property than font-weight. I would user the safari remote debugger for this and see exactly which properties are being applied to the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with following modification at **.text**:

```
font-size: 26px;
font-weight: 100;
```

Comment: So, I was using font-weight: 500, in reality font-weight: 400 is "normal".  It seems that iOS Safari was sensitive to this and made buttons bold, but other font-weight: 500 text was kept as normal.